# Doctrine mysql, check if array in other array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have in my database an array field.

If i look i have that : `a:3:{i:0;s:10:"23-09-2014";i:1;s:10:"24-09-2014";i:2;s:10:"01-10-2014";}`

In my controller, i create an other array from a string with :

```
$array = explode(",", '01-02-2014, 02-03-2014, 03-04-2014');
```

I want to know, with `createQueryBuilder()` if all dates of my array `$array` are in my field in database... Like `$query->where('All_my_date_in_$array ARE IN my_array_field')`

Do you know a way for do that ? Thanks !

Comment: is this array has any predefined structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be possible by using wild card search on your serialized data save in your column like loop through your dates array and in loop add where clause with each data to match,this is bad because dates should saved as their real date type and for the serialized you should store it as by making relational tables for more see [`Database normalization`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('u');
$i=1;
foreach($dates as $date){
if($i== 1){
         $query->where( 'u.your_column_name LIKE  :date_'.$i);
}else{
        $query->andWhere( 'u.your_column_name LIKE  :date_'.$i);
}
        $query->setParameter('date_'.$i, '%'.$date.'%');
$i++;
}
$result= $query->getQuery()
               ->getResult();
```

so this will match `your_column_name` for each date in your array with `and` operation and the result set will be returned which contain these dates